# Solidity Declaration error related to Wallets in Money paid fuction

Tags: function, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I'm new to solidity

My goal is to get this code to work in remix IDE solidity compiler

The code is a "for" function that is meant to trigger when deceased = true, (The code is for an inheritance contract) but it is having problems with "wallet" part of the code on the final two lines.

I've tried looking on here and elsewhere (such as Solidity/Remix IDE documentation) to find a solution but struggling with this particular problem.

Ive tried removing the "[i]", adding ";" and adding a underscore at the beginning wallet (such as "_wallets")

ive been told that i have declare the wallets but i have no clue how you do that

This is the Inheritance contract code in full:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
//import solidity 
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Inheritance { 
    address owner;
    bool deceased;
    uint money;
    

    constructor () public payable {
        owner = msg.sender;
        money = msg.value;
        deceased = false;

}

modifier oneOwner {
    require (msg.sender == owner);
    _;
}

modifier isDeceased {
    require (deceased == true);
    _;

address [0xa1F9019E4F941071cAabCbb3fBc6314c06BeD18f] wallets;

mapping (address => uint) inheritance;
}

function setup(address _wallet, uint _inheritance) public oneOwner {
    _wallet.push(_wallet);
    Inheritance [_wallet] = _inheritance; 
}

function moneyPaid() private isDeceased {
    for (uint i=0; i< wallets.length; i++) {
        wallets[i].transfer(Inheritance[wallets][i]);
    }
}

function died() public oneOwner { 
    deceased = true; 
    moneyPaid();
}
}
```

These are the errors i get:

```
DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
--> Inheritance contract 1.1.sol:38:20:
|
38 | for (uint i=0; i< wallets.length; i++) {
|                      ^^^^^^^




DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
--> Inheritance contract 1.1.sol:39:3:
|
39 | wallets;[i].transfer(Inheritance[wallets][i]);
|    ^^^^^^^


DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
--> Inheritance contract 1.1.sol:39:36:
|
39 | wallets;[i].transfer(Inheritance[wallets][i]);
|                                     ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

your storage variable wallets was inside the modifier.. you have to declare state variable outside the modifier..

```
 modifier isDeceased {
    require (deceased == true);
    _;
}

address [0xa1F9019E4F941071cAabCbb3fBc6314c06BeD18f] wallets;
mapping (address => uint) inheritance;

// }   --> not here
```